# convert string array into integer array android

Tags: android, performance

I created a url string array.

```
String urls[]={"http://www.kllhjj.png","http://yui.kl.png"};
```

this url are not exactly correct. But in my code them are correct. Then I try to convert them into integer array just like following way.

```
int a[] = new int[urls.length];

for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
   try {
      a[i] = Integer.parseInt(urls[i]);
   }
   catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

But here always show the a integer values as 0. why is it?
help me

Comment: Never a good practice to Catch all Exceptions

Comment: What would you _expect_ to be the result of converting `http://www.kllhjj.png` to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Integer.parseInt(urls[i]);` is throwing `NumberFormatException` and **you are swallowing the `Exception`** . The below code will not work in your case, but at least you will get to know the error:

```
try{
     a[i]=Integer.parseInt(urls[i]);
   }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     throw new RunTimeException(e);
 }
```

**All the elements of a primitive `int` array are defaulted to `0`.** Hence you get the `0`s .

You cannot parse string like `"http://yui.kl.png"` etc to `int` as they are not in numeric format .  Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> **Throws:**
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `NumberFormatException` Exception hence not changing any values in `a[]` and because the default values of integer is `0` you are having 0 for every element in `a[]`

Answer (score 0):

Urls are text string and you parsing text to int:

```
a[i]=Integer.parseInt(urls[i]);
```

which through an exception absorbed by:

```
catch(Exception e)
```

and default value for int is zero so u always getting it.

Answer (score 0):

ParseInt is a function that search for integer in some string. it's like `atoi` if you're familiar with c language.

When you have a string that contains only letters it will return 0.

When you have a string that begins with letter and ends with number it also will return 0.

It will convert a string to integer if the string will contains a number characters like "0123".

I don't know what you're trying to do, but if you want that number will represent a url. 
I think you can create an enum for the urls.